React native - Duplicate resources during merg
I am currently attempting to set-up my react native application to support multiple environment configurations. To achieve this I am attempting to utilize the react-native-config module.
Once installed and attempting to run this command:
yarn react-native run-android --mode=developmentDebug --appIdSuffix=development

I recieve the following error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDevelopmentDebugResources'.
> [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png   [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\build\generated\res\react\developmentDebug\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativepaper_src_assets_backchevron] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnativepaper_src_assets_backchevron.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativepaper_src_assets_backchevron] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\build\generated\res\react\developmentDebug\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnativepaper_src_assets_backchevron.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\build\generated\res\react\developmentDebug\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backiconmask] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backiconmask.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backiconmask] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\build\generated\res\react\developmentDebug\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backiconmask.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_icons_csv] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_icons_csv.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_icons_csv] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\build\generated\res\react\developmentDebug\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_icons_csv.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_icons_jpg] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_icons_jpg.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_icons_jpg] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\build\generated\res\react\developmentDebug\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_icons_jpg.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_icons_pdf] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_icons_pdf.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_icons_pdf] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\build\generated\res\react\developmentDebug\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_icons_pdf.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_icons_png] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_icons_png.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_icons_png] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\build\generated\res\react\developmentDebug\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_icons_png.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_icons_txt] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_icons_txt.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_icons_txt] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\build\generated\res\react\developmentDebug\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_icons_txt.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_icons_xls] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_icons_xls.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_icons_xls] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\build\generated\res\react\developmentDebug\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_icons_xls.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_icons_xlsx] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_icons_xlsx.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_icons_xlsx] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\build\generated\res\react\developmentDebug\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_icons_xlsx.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_icons_zip] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_icons_zip.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_icons_zip] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\build\generated\res\react\developmentDebug\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_icons_zip.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_icons__blank] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_icons__blank.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_icons__blank] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\build\generated\res\react\developmentDebug\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_icons__blank.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png [drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\build\generated\res\react\developmentDebug\drawable-xhdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png   [drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\build\generated\res\react\developmentDebug\drawable-xxhdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxxhdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png [drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] D:\Development\recqrd\android\app\build\generated\res\react\developmentDebug\drawable-xxxhdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources

I have tried a number of things including removing these assets and also re-bundling the resources, both to no avail.
packages.json
{
  "name": "recqrd",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^3.1.0",
    "@react-native/gradle-plugin": "^0.73.4",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.11",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.1",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^5.26.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "geolib": "^3.3.4",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.4",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.19.11",
    "react-native-config": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^8.1.3",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.15.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-gradle-plugin": "^0.71.19",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-input-prompt": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-maps": "1.15.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.1.3",
    "react-native-paper-dropdown": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-tooltip": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^3.9.0",
    "react-native-windows": "^0.75.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.0",
    "@react-native/js-polyfills": "^0.74.0",
    "@react-native/metro-babel-transformer": "^0.73.15",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.73.5",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-config": "^0.80.6",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.5",
    "metro-runtime": "^0.80.6",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

Is there any alternate modules, or other things to try with this module?
